# Manual modifications of the class definition of a Reference Class instance

Tags: r, reference-class

I'm aware that this would be a terribly unreliable hack. But out of pure interest:

What would you need to manually change in the `.refClassDef` field of an ref class object if the Reference Class definition of an already instantiated object changed and you would like it to "be informed about the update" (without re-instantiating it).

After all, it does seem to work if *additional* methods are introduced, but not for modifications of *existing* methods (see example below).

This question is related to my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492219/how-to-tell-an-r-reference-class-object-to-update-its-method-definitions/22492863#22492863).

---

### Example

Original class def:

```
MyReferenceClass <- setRefClass("MyReferenceClass",
    methods = list(
        print_hello = function(){
            print("hello")
        }
    )
)
```

Instantiate:

```
my_object <- MyReferenceClass$new()
my_object$print_hello()
[1] "hello"
```

Updated class def:

```
MyReferenceClass <- setRefClass("MyReferenceClass",
    methods = list(
        print_hello = function(){
            print("hello_again")
        },
        print_goodbye = function(){
            print("goodbye")
        }
    )
)
```

Instance can use the new method:

```
my_object$print_goodbye()
[1] "goodbye"
```

But it would for example fail to be informed about changes in `print_hello` as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492219/how-to-tell-an-r-reference-class-object-to-update-its-method-definitions/22492863#22492863) illustrates.

Answer (score 1):

Include an `update` method in your class (before and after modification). Call `obj$update()` before calling another method upon any updates of the class.

```
MyReferenceClass <- setRefClass(
  "MyReferenceClass",
  methods = list(
    print_hello = function(){
      print("hello")
    },
    update = function(){
      selfEnv <- as.environment(.self)
      .class <- as.character(class(.self))
      for (e in as.vector(utils::lsf.str(selfEnv))){ 
        v <- get(e,eval(parse(text=sprintf("%s@generator$def@refMethods",.class))))
        assign(e,v,envir=selfEnv)
      }
    }
    )
  )
```

**UPDATE: Wed Jun 11** The `update` method now asks for a vector of methods to be updated, to avoid accidentally changes of internal methods. Thanks to @Rappster for pointing this out.

```
MyReferenceClass <- setRefClass(
  "MyReferenceClass",
  methods = list(
    print_hello = function(){
      print("hello")
    },
    update = function(x){
      selfEnv <- as.environment(.self)
      .class <- as.character(class(.self))
      for (e in x){
        v <- get(e,eval(parse(text=sprintf("%s@generator$def@refMethods",.class))))
        assign(e,v,envir=selfEnv)
      }
    }
    )
  )

obj <- MyReferenceClass$new()
obj$print_hello()

## ...
obj$update('print_hello')
```

Comment: Nice approach! But I think the manual assignment destroys the internal self-referencing structure: once you ran `update()`, none of the methods are able to use/find `.self` anymore in subsequent calls. Just try running `update()` twice in a row. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: @Rappster Sorry for coming back late. And yes, there are indeed some conflicts when making `update` in a blind manner, due to changes in internal methods. I will update the code to only allow updates on custom-specified methods.